# Crear un heatmap a partir de una lista de pixeles (coordenadas) con valores

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, seaborn

tengo una lista tal que esta:

[image: Tabla]

Donde el valor de cada píxel puede ser desde 0 a 400 (da la casualidad que muchos píxeles son 2).

Mi idea es hacer un heatmap (mapa de intensidades) donde pueda representar estas coordenadas por colores (cada cordenada que sea un punto en el píxel de la imagen).

He probado con:

```
print(sns.heatmap(df))
```

Siendo df la tabla

Muchas gracias.

PREGUNTA ACTUALIZADA: Mirad los comentarios para ver a qué me refiero

[image: Voltear imagen]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comencemos por crear unos datos aleatorios para hacer pruebas:

```
import random

coords = []
values = []
for _ in range(50000):
  x = random.randint(1, 1050)
  y = random.randint(1, 525)
  v = random.randint(1, 400)
  coords.append((x,y))
  values.append(v)

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Coordinates": coords, "Value": values})
```

El dataframe así creado tiene esta pinta:

```
      Coordinates  Value
0       (255, 54)    189
1      (582, 524)    180
2      (852, 279)     75
3      (803, 132)      7
4      (322, 149)    280
...           ...    ...
49995  (119, 145)    294
49996   (936, 32)    218
49997  (1026, 83)    288
49998  (847, 197)    116
49999  (777, 505)    119

[50000 rows x 2 columns]
```

El siguiente paso es separar las tuplas que hay en la columna "Coordinates" y crear con ellas otras dos columnas que llamaré "x" e "y", y añadiré al mismo dataframe:

```
df[["x", "y"]] = pd.DataFrame(df.Coordinates.to_list())
```

Ahora el dataframe tiene este aspecto:

```
  Coordinates  Value    x    y
0   (255, 54)    189  255   54
1  (582, 524)    180  582  524
2  (852, 279)     75  852  279
3  (803, 132)      7  803  132
4  (322, 149)    280  322  149
```

El siguiente paso es crear un array bidimensional, para lo que usaré numpy. Inicialmente todos los elementos de ese array serán ceros. El tamaño de ese array depende de los valores máximos en las columnas "x" e "y" del dataframe anterior:

```
import numpy as np
matriz = np.zeros((df.x.max()+1, df.y.max()+1))
```

Y ahora se rellenan elementos de ese array, usando las coordenadas `[x,y]` y la columna de valores. Esto se puede hacer sin necesidad de bucles, en una sola operación "vectorizada":

```
matriz[df.x, df.y] = df.Value
```

Ya solo queda pintar el heatmap, lo que seaborn puede hacer directamente desde la matriz numpy:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.heatmap(matriz)
```

El resultado (poco llamativo en este caso) es:

[image: Resultado]

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, era eso lo que necesitaba. Me pregunto cómo hay que hacerlo para voltear el heatmap si no es mucho pedir. Muchas gracias otra vez, no tenía ni la menor idea de cómo hacerlo.

Comment: He actualizado la pregunta para que puedas entenderme correctamente. Mi intención es rotar la imagen 90 grados hacia el sentido de las agujas del reloj. De nuevo, muchas gracias.

Comment: Cómo se puede hacer para guardar el heatmap? .save? Gracias.

Comment: Deberías incluir estas cuestiones en tu pregunta, en  lugar de referirte a los comentarios (y quizás entonces borrar estos comentarios). Puedes pintar la transpuesta de la matriz con `snb.heatmap(matriz.T)`. Eso intercambia filas por columnas. No es exactamente lo mismo que girar 90º pero si te sirve, es mucho más simple. Para guardar la figura has de usar `.get_figure().savefig("ej.png")`